# What is the benefit of using this type param in web.xml

Tags: jsp, servlets, web.xml

I was reading a book about Servlet and the book used  **context-param**  and
**init-param**,  but he did not provide an example of how to use it. He just explain it in few words. Can some one give me example about how to use it and why I need it in my xml file?

NOTE: I am not talking about **servlet-name** and  **servlet-class**. I am talking about the other two param.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>custEmail</param-name>
    <param-value>isadfj@gmail.com</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>addEmailListServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>email.addEmailListServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>reletivePathFile</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/Email.txt</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Answer (score 1):

They are initial parameter, you would get them with `init(c:ServletConfig):void` method, where once container instantiate the servlet, it will invoke init method and include the initial parameter provided by `web.xml` file to the instance.

So they do no do any magic, or anything, just initial parameter, they are very useful when something need to be configed at the start of servlet life, for example default email, or pool size, or external path name, anything.

for instance

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>sys_mail</param-name>
    <param-value>root@my-daemon.com</param-value>
</init-param>
```

And where the servlet

```
public void init(ServletConfig c) throws ServletException{
        c.getInitParameter("sys_mail");//this will return root@my-daemon.com
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are Sending `InitParameter`Request  From Servlet Like

```
 this.myParam = servletConfig.getInitParameter("myParam");
```

then for Access this we can mapped on `Web.xml` like :-

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>myParam</param-name>
    <param-value>paramValue</param-value>
 </init-param>
```

Coming on `Context Parameters` Side . here we passed request on Servlet :

```
String myContextParam =request.getSession().getServletContext().getInitParameter("myParam");
```

Then for Access `myContextParam`we can mapped on `web.xml` like :-

```
<context-param>
<param-name>myParam</param-name>
<param-value>the value</param-value>
</context-param>
```